# How to test if today is not after a specific date?

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate

In Objective-C, how to test if today is not after a specific date?

I am using the following way but am curious if there is a better way or other alternatives to go about this.

> ```
> NSString *dateString = @"20140928";
> NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
> [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
> NSDate *expirationDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
> NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
> if ([today laterDate:expirationDate] != today) {
>     NSLog(@"Today is not after expirationDate");
> }
> ```

Comment: That's more or less it.  There are a few different ways to to the actual compare, and you may or may not want to fudge the time-of-day values one way or the other so that the compare will be true or false for the entire day of the match vs just up to the current time of day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code is getting the expiration date so that doesn't really count.

Once you have the date then using `laterDate:` or `compare:` with `[NSDate date]` are two simple ways.

You could also do:

```
if ([expirationDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
    // expiration date is after "now"
}
```

This avoids the need to use `[NSDate date]`.

Comment: I like the fact that there is no need to create another date.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative there is:

```
if ([today compare:expirationDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
    // expirationDate comes "after" today

if ([today compare:expirationDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
    // expirationDate comes "before" today

if ([today compare:expirationDate] == NSOrderedSame)
    // expirationDate equals today
```

Comment: "equals today" it very unlikely to happen and misleading. it means they are the same day and same time.

Comment: Yes Bryan, you are correct (well, that the two compared date instances are the same).  Let's leave it to the developer and the others who might benefit from the code snippet to decide for themselves how useful it is, shall we?  Troll ...